# How can I get Visual Studio Code to reset the IntelliSense engine for Rust?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, intellisense

I am working on two projects, one is a library, the other is a program that uses that library. When I make changes to the library the other window (the program) doesn't see these changes, so I do not get updated IntelliSense. Closing the program that uses the library and reopening it does force an update but I really prefer not having to go that far.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: Rust - rust-lang.rust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the title directly and not the root issue...

You can reset IntelliSense and all Rust code features by running the "Rust: Restart the Rust server" command from the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

[image]

Progress will be indicated in the status bar.

Still a blunt tool but it will ensure you're in a fresh state without having to restart VS Code entirely.

Comment: I'll note that this shouldn't be necessary depending on your setup. I use multiple crates regularly without intellisense issues though that might be because they're in the same [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html). Including more of your configuration in your question might get you a fix rather than a workaround.

Comment: I'll look more into workspaces. Currently they are two completely separate projects.