# Why VSCode does not suggest me anything?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, intellisense

I just started learning Rust and tried to write make a simple HTTP request using `reqwest`

I tried to create a `reqwest::Client`, but VSCode didn't give me a corresponding completion.

[image: Screenshot]

But after I wrote the code myself, VSCode showed me that it knows the type of the expression.

[image: Screenshot]

And after I wrote `let res = client.`, it still does not give me any completion about this.

[image: Screenshot]

Why can this happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62975871/109941

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14154753/109941

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the `Rust` extension for VSCode instead of `rust-analyzer`. Both of these extensions provide a language server, which ultimately is what's responsible for code suggestions.

I ran into similar problems with subpar autocomplete when using VSCode with the `Rust` extension. Uninstalling that, and installing the `rust-analyzer` extension instead, resulted in a far superior experience. The `rust-analyzer` language server is now also officially recommended moving forwards, as stated [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2912-rust-analyzer.html):

> The RFC proposes a plan to adopt rust-analyzer as Rust's official LSP implementation.

where `LSP` is an acronym for Language Server Protocol.